# How to conditionally select value with JQ

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to select 1 price if it exists, otherwise I want to select a "default" price which always exists. My JQ works if the RMP price doesn't exist, I just get the 1 value back. But as you can see, if RMP exists I end up with 2 entries ... one with each price. I am only looking for 1 result back. It will either have the RMP price if it exists, or it will have the RET price. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

JSON

```
[
  {
    "PartNumber": "ABC123",
    "Prices": {
      "Pricing": [
        {
          "@PriceType": "RET",
          "Price": {
            "#text": "230.3800"
          }
        },
        {
          "@PriceType": "LST",
          "Price": {
            "#text": "230.3800"
          }
        },
        {
          "@PriceType": "RMP",
          "Price": {
            "#text": "152.0000"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

JQ

```
[.[] | {
    sku: .PartNumber,
    price: (.Prices?.Pricing? | if type == "array" then .[] else . end | if any(.; ."@PriceType" == "RMP") then select(."@PriceType"? == "RMP").Price."#text" else select(."@PriceType"? == "RET").Price."#text" end),
}]
```

RESULT

```
[
  {
    "sku": "ABC123",
    "price": "230.3800"
  },
  {
    "sku": "ABC123",
    "price": "152.0000"
  }
]
```

Comment: I'd be cautious about using jq over a general purpose programming language for this kind of problem tbh, especially if it yields actionable decisions and involves real money.

Comment: @jarmod I'd argue that jq is Turing-complete, so it can perform any data transformation you can imagine. And it does it declaratively (i.e. in a data-oriented manner), so its correctness is far easier to prove. Also, by not being a general-purpose programming language (i.e it can't make http requests, alter files on disk, etc.), it doesn't add to the processing it's embedded into another attack vector for nefarious activities, especially if it "involves real money". The actions logic should be done elsewhere (and only there), while jq can assist by providing robust solutions in its domain.

Comment: @pmf all good points and undoubtedly jq is a really valuable tool. My concern is simply that there are very few people who understand jq at all well, partly because its syntax is so challenging, and it's therefore hard to get right. Also, using it in a bash script pipeline is less likely to be unit-tested so authors may miss edge case where it breaks for them (because they don't have the knowledge).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "problem" of your approach is with `if type == "array" then .[] else . end`. As `.Prices.Pricing` is indeed an array, this branches to `.[]`, destructuring the array, so the following code is executed three times, once for each item. The first one will produce the default item (as there is nothing else), the second outputs nothing (neither the target nor the default is present), and the third immediately finds the target item.

My approach would be using `INDEX` to turn the array into an object, and the alternative operator `//` to select a default if the previous returns null:

```bash
map({
  sku: .PartNumber,
  price: (.Prices.Pricing | INDEX(."@PriceType") | .RMP // .RET | .Price."#text")
})
```

```json
[
  {
    "sku": "ABC123",
    "price": "152.0000"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/RwHYZpHFPEx)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help. Is there a way to "visualize" what's going on, or just learning JQ and knowing?

Comment: @slapyo I don't know of any jq code visualizers (but it would definitely be a fun project to write). Fwiw, I find jq's language fairly intuitive if you already have experience with FPLs (like [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), or [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/), or even [Nushell](https://www.nushell.sh/)), while not being radically paradigm-shifting if you don't. Once you get the basic hang of it, it's really just straight forward from there. Personally, I've learned a lot by looking at how builtins are defined using jq itself: https://github.com/jqlang/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq

Comment: @slapyo Regarding the expression that broke your approach: If its intent was to account for values that might be either a single object or an array of multiple objects (typically produced by converters from XML/HTML for sibling nodes having the same name), you could use `//` again to collect array items or, if there wasn't an array, the single value into a new array using `… .Pricing | [arrays[] // .] | INDEX …`, where `arrays` is just a shortcut for `select(type == "array")` (see the [builtin.jq](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/blob/913b26469f47351a9f75a1bc4145f45421115e37/src/builtin.jq#L54))